# Need line generalization method like Dougles Peuker, that is able to keep turning points along closed polygon boundaries (for 2d or 3d point data)

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I have set of point clouds, representing boundaries of different closed polygons. These polygons contains 3d points. But they also can be considered as a 2d case once boundary points are projected to the xy plane. Though these boundaries are irregular, it can be fitted into small, straight line segments. I am trying to do this fitting by least square method. But, before that, I want to identify the turning points or the corresponding point sets for each straight line segment which I am going to fit. So, I am looking for a good, fast method. I know that the dougles-peuker algorithm could be used to reduce the points along the boundary and then to identify the turning points. But, I feel it would not be giving me major turning spots like 20, 45, 90, degrees... turnings of the  boundary.

1. if anyone can point out a robust method to find major turning points along 
   the boundary it is highly grateful.
2. also, please tell me, how can i combine dougles-peuker algorithm and least square
   fitting to get straight line segments together with available turns (if any) like
   20,45,90,..degrees in between consecutive line segments.
3. may be, one can give me some other methods or if can give me some related papers which 
   is able to detect turning points of the point boundaries.
4. actually i am looking for point generalization algorithm which is able to keep turning 
   points.

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

For 2d curves, check out [Efficient Curve Fitting](http://jgt.akpeters.com/papers/Frisken08/).

See also *An Algorithm for Automatically Fitting Digitized Curves* by Schneider, in [Graphics Gems](http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gems.html#gems). The code is [available](http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gems/FitCurves.c).

Comment: @ihf> thank you. but, it is not able to access to that paper..

Comment: @g_niro: deceptively, maybe, his name is lhf (LHF) instead of ihf (IHF). Secondly, you can find the check-out page for that paper [here](http://akpeters.metapress.com/content/j5477497415x1256/?p=4800300990f84156bf51c0fb3afdef25&pi=3) - it does cost 15 dollars though.

Comment: @g_niro, or you could ask the author for a copy: http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~frisken/frisken.html

Comment: dear all..looking for some other methods..please

Comment: @g_niro: I've added another reference.